# Paypal IPN errors in Magento store

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.5, paypal-ipn

Every order placed from the frontend of our Magento store logs a "Wrong order ID" exception even though all orders seem to be going through with no problems.  Orders also seem to take a lot longer to complete than they should.  If I place an order from the admin, it's virtually instantaneous and does not log any errors.  What's different between frontend and backend orders?  Why are these errors being logged every time even though no error really occurred?  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I just added some logging to the IpnController.php as well as to the Ipn.php files.  It's a bit early to tell, but it seems that this has helped alleviate some (if not all) of the errors.  Could this be a timing issue?  Perhaps the IPN callback happens before the order is saved in Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [change log for Magento 1.7.0.0](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.7.0.0%20%28Apr%2024,%202012%29) (which came out in April), they think they've fixed the problem:

```
Fixed: “Wrong order ID” exception in PayPal Express module under heavy load
```

Can anyone confirm that upgrading to Magento 1.7 does indeed fix the problem?  Every time I've looked at it, it does seem to be a PayPal Express issue (our payments normally go through PayPal Pro and that doesn't seem to have errors).

Comment: I'd love to hear from someone who had this problem, has upgraded to 1.7.0.0, and no longer has the problem.  Upgrading is probably not in the cards for us any time soon, but if I could update the 1.5.0.1 code with whatever changes they made to fix it, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

So... we finally found a permanent solution to this for Magento 1.6. And we can confirm that this has been fixed in Magento 1.7.

Full explanation and code here:

[Magento Paypal IPN Wrong Order ID – SOLVED](http://www.bigdune.net/geek-blog/magento/60-magento-paypal-ipn-wrong-order-id.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for updating this question with your findings.  I have not had a chance to try it yet, but it looks good and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same exception in Magento 1.6.1 showing up in exception.log. The problem for us was that the Order Number and Invoice Numbers were out of sync.

For some reason, when using PayPal Express, it causes the order to not be fully processed and logs the exception: “Wrong Order ID”. The worst part was that it was erratic… sometimes it would fail, other times it was fine.

THE SOLUTION:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-sameorderinvoicenumber.html

Thanks for a great extension from Fooman! Just install their “SameOrderInvoiceNumber” extension, remember to enable it in “Configuration | Sales | Order Numbers” and you’re all set!

Solved the problem for us on Magento 1.6.1… don’t mess with core code!

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, but we already have that extension installed and we're still getting this problem.  It IS a great extension though :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok... So my other solution didn't soIve the problem for us either. Spoke too soon. Although this helped it didn't get rid of the error completely.

We did however find a definite clear link between server load and this IPN error. Detailed analysis here:
http://www.bigdune.net/geek-blog/magento/60-magento-paypal-ipn-wrong-order-id.html

Sorry, but it doesn't seem like there's a quick "code fix" for this one.. not that we could find yet.